# How to query MySQL if a datetime falls within any of multiple datetime ranges

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have one table which I can extract a bunch of date ranges from.
I have another table with a list of events.
I'd like to know how to get all rows of events where the date of the event falls in a date range, and join it with the range.

In the example below, the events with ID 1,2,5 would be returned since they are within a range in the range table.

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-03 19:00:25 | 2022-10-03 19:32:55 |
| 2022-10-03 19:32:58 | 2022-10-03 19:33:15 |
| 2022-10-03 19:33:51 | 2022-10-03 19:34:25 |
| 2022-10-03 19:41:19 | 2022-10-03 19:46:21 |

| id | data | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | load | 2022-10-03 19:00:40 |
| 2 | 2 | unload | 2022-10-03 19:10:10 |
| 3 | 3 | load | 2022-10-03 19:32:56 |
| 4 | 64 | other | 2022-10-03 19:34:50 |
| 5 | 21 | load | 2022-10-03 19:42:00 |

I made one table as a subquery with date ranges, but I can't seem to connect it to the events table.

```
select start_idle_time as start, DATE_ADD(start_idle_time, INTERVAL idle_duration second) as end from summarized_idle_times
```

I also tried with multiple subqueries, but it doesn't work because the subqueries return multiple rows.

```
select * from devices_data 
where type in ('unload', 'load') 
and devices_data.date between 
(select start_idle_time as start from summarized_idle_times)
and 
(select DATE_ADD(start_idle_time, INTERVAL idle_duration second) as end from summarized_idle_times)
order by devices_data.date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the date range condition on the join clause

```
select dd.*
from devices_data dd 
inner join summarized_idle_times sit on  (dd.`date` >= sit.`start`) AND (dd.`date` <= sit.`end`);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/bpFNxjMu

Comment: Thanks @Ergest. This works. But it is VERY slow... 

The full query I built is:
select summarized_idle_times.idle_duration, summarized_idle_times.start_idle_time, type from devices_data 
join summarized_idle_times on 
 ((devices_data.`date` >= summarized_idle_times.`start_idle_time`) 
  AND 
 (devices_data.`date` <= DATE_ADD(summarized_idle_times.start_idle_time, INTERVAL summarized_idle_times.idle_duration second)))
where type in ('unload', 'load') limit 10

Comment: @BenWeisblatt performance is another issue, I suggest you open a new question for the performance and add table description, explain plan